# Langchain streaming response

Tags: python, langchain

Been trying to make an q and a bot.

Tried several versions of code but I am getting questions inside the answer for some reason. For example if I ask 'what is pql?' it will answer correctly. If then I say 'tell me more', the answer will still be correct but it will start with a question like this 'Where can I find more information about PQL?'

```
conversation = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
                llm=ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",temperature=0, streaming=True, callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
                retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
                memory=self.memory
            )
conversation({"question": self.question, 'chat_history': self.memory})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to properly configure `PromptTemplate` and use `ConversationChain` with `memory`

```py
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = """You're a helpful assistant, aiming at solving the problem.

Relevant pieces of previous conversation:
{history}

(You do not need to use these pieces of information if not relevant)

Answer my question: {input}
"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
   input_variables=["history", "input"], template=_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
)


from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
conversation_with_summary = ConversationChain(
   llm=llm,
   prompt=PROMPT,
   memory=memory,
   verbose=True
)

conversation_with_summary.predict(input=user_input)
```